# AKS create with App gateway ingress control fails with IngressAppGwAddonConfigInvalidSubnetCIDRNotContainedWithinVirtualNetwork error

Tags: azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

When i try to create aks using azure cli using the following command :

**"az aks create -n myCluster -g myResourceGroup --network-plugin azure --enable-managed-identity -a ingress-appgw --appgw-name myApplicationGateway --appgw-subnet-cidr "10.2.0.0/16" --generate-ssh-keys"**

I get the below error.

**"(IngressAppGwAddonConfigInvalidSubnetCIDRNotContainedWithinVirtualNetwork) Subnet Prefix '10.2.0.0/16' specified for IngressApplicationGateway addon is not contained within the AKS Agent Pool's Virtual Network address prefixes '[10.224.0.0/12]'.
Code: IngressAppGwAddonConfigInvalidSubnetCIDRNotContainedWithinVirtualNetwork
Message: Subnet Prefix '10.2.0.0/16' specified for IngressApplicationGateway addon is not contained within the AKS Agent Pool's Virtual Network address prefixes '[10.224.0.0/12]'.
Target: AddonProfiles.IngressApplicationGateway"**

Any idea why i get this error ? or how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you have used the [Tutorial: Enable the Ingress Controller add-on for a new AKS cluster with a new Application Gateway instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-new) tutorial.

I had some trouble creating a new AKS cluster with a command similar to yours. For `azure-cli` version `2.35.0` in Apr 06, 2022 when it was released the command you issued worked fine.

Something changed that broke the tutorial so... The Subnet CIDR you specify with `--appgw-subnet-cidr` should be a `/16` subnet in the usable host range of `10.224.0.0/12`.

That leaves you with the choice between the range of `10.224.0.0 - 10.239.0.0`. I used subnet `10.225.0.0/16` for my deployment.

Answer (score 1):

***Seems your AKS cluster Virtual Network address space is overlap with virtual network of application gateway***

> When using an AKS cluster and Application Gateway in separate virtual
> networks, the address spaces of the two virtual networks must not
> overlap.The default address space that an AKS cluster deploys in is
> 10.0.0.0/8. so we set the Application Gateway virtual network address prefix to 11.0.0.0/8.

Would suggest you to please refer this [***microsft document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-existing) to ***Enable the AGIC add-on in existing AKS cluster through Azure CLI*** to avoid the error.

Comment: I don't want  to add an existing app gateway to the new cluster. I need the App gateway created as part of the AKS cluster creation.